# How do you vertically align a navbar within a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have seen a couple other posts indicating that you have to have a container with h-100 to align items with the align-self class however I am running into problems getting a navbar aligned at the bottom of a div. If I stick the navbar within another container and row it works however then the navbar is not the full width of the main container. Here is what I have:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 body-content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light align-self-lg-end">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="logo_banner">
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Thanks, all help is appreciated.

Comment: `container-fluid` comes with a default `padding-left:15px;` and `padding-right:15px` , to make your nave full width, you'll need to get rid of those : `.container-fluid{ padding-left:0; padding-right:0;}`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the class .align-middle.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/